# Pi not responding

Tags: raspbian, boot

When I switch my RPi on, it comes up with the error

```
 script failed service py, url error unable to connect to server, and unable to connect to host.
```

Also getting `Add on has been marked as broken in repository. Would you like to disable it on your system?`

I cannot click on the yes\no boxes as the Pi then freezes.  I bought the Pi fully installed with Raspbian. I have tried to contact the seller, but they are no longer trading.

Comment: If it is brand new, then perhaps install Rasbian fresh? Well first of all is it raspbian? :P
You could format communicates in some sort of code block for readability. Did you try ssh from different computer?

Answer (score 2):

You should just reinstall your Raspberry Pi with a fresh OS. I assume you're using something with Kodi?

Raspbmc: http://edge.samnazarko.co.uk/raspbmc/raspbmc-final-25032015.img.gz

Other available OS: 
- https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/
- http://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv6/raspberry-pi
- https://github.com/debian-pi/raspbian-ua-netinst (Raspbian minimal netinstaller - recommended )

If you're on Windows use Win32 Disk Imager to write he .img files to your Raspberry Pi SD card.